# CMake dependencies between libraries and programs

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm a beginner with CMake and since yesterday I try something without result :-(

I explain my goal... I've a C++ project with dynamic libraries and programs using these libraries.

Here is the structure of my project:

- libA
- libB
- program1
- program2
- program3

Inside each directory, I've an include and a src directory.

libB uses libA, program1 program2 and program3 use libA and libB.

I've a CMakeLists.txt in each directory (even in the root directory). I'm able to build each lib and program individually (without dependencies) but I don't know how to define dependencies between them.

For example, I would like the include files of the libraries to be known by the programs, the same for the link of .dll

Could someone help me on this topic? Thanks for your answers :-)

Regards.

Comment: You should build such a project only from the top CMakeLists (where you fo add_subdirectory) for the subdirectories and you could use target_link_library to link other targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to define dependencies between them.

Just, in respective CMakeLists:

```
target_link_libraries(program1 PRIVATE libA libB)
target_link_libraries(program2 PRIVATE libA libB)
target_link_libraries(program3 PRIVATE libA libB)
target_link_libraries(libB PUBLIC LIBA)
```